# Wamp, WordPress LDAP

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap, wamp

Hi I am trying to use active directory for my WordPress site (intranet). I have tried a few plugins and none of them have worked so far. I want to stick with `Active Directory Integration V1.1.5` as it is one of the most feature rich for my needs.

The issue I am having is that I have My WAMP server installed (Windows User). When I check my

- Apache modules says `ldap_module` is enabled
- PhP extensions says `php_ldap` is enabled

But it does not work. The plugin I am using has a testing tool and the result returned is as follows.

`AD Integration Logon Test - openLDAP not installed`

Looking at my settings it all seems to be installed correctly. Some other things I have tried:

- Went to `\\manmd01\c$\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\modules` and made sure that mod_ldap.so exists.
- I've gone into `\\manmd01\c$\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf` and made sure that this line is not commented out: LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
- I've gone into `\\manmd01\c$\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` and made sure this line is not commented out: extension=php_ldap.dll

I have looked at other posts (on stack overflow) and tried to replicate the fixes but so far nothing appears to have worked for me this is why i am asking the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ini file that is used by Apache is not the `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini`.

If you use the wampmanager menus ( they are there for a reason )

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

It will edit the correct file, which for reference is `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\phpForApache.ini`.

If you uncomment the ldap extension in there you will have more luck.

Alternatively, you can use the wampmanager menus ( they are there for a reason ) to turn on the ldap extension.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> Extensions -> php_ldap
```

If this menu item does not have a tick beside it, then click it, it will automaticalyy amend the CORRECT ini file and then restart Apache so that the change is activated.

NOTE: The php.ini file in `\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` is only used by the PHP CLI (Command Line Interpreter)

Also the php_ldap extension requires 3 other dll's to be available in order to run. These are :-

- libsasl.dll
- libeay32.dll
- ssleay32.dll

The old way, WAMPServer 2.4 and before was to copy these to the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` but there is a better way as of 2.5.

On WAMPServer 2.5 these are located in the \wamp\bin\php{version}\php` folder. There should be SYMLINKS created inside the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` folder by the install. If these SYMLINKS do not exist, then to recreate all the required SYMLNKS the easiest way is to use the wampmanager menus to recreate them. You do this by :-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9 (i.e. click on the version number)
```

Comment: I checked both, Sorry I didn't state in the question. They have ticks next to them

Comment: This did help me understand a bit more about it though

Comment: I just remembered that php_ldap is of course dependant upon 3 other dll's I have edited my answer. Hope this is more helpful

Comment: Sorry but `SYMLINK`? I am not 100% sure what i am looking for. Other than that the 3 dll files are in the PHP folder. The Apache folder contains 2 of the DLL's but is missing `libsasl.dll`.

Comment: Just do what I suggested at the bottom of the answer to recreate all the SYMLINK's and that should sort that out. Here is a doc on Windows SymLnks or Junctions as they are called on Windows [NTFS symbolic links in Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) They have been around since Windows XP, but not many people knew about them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start → Control Panel)
2. Go to the Advanced tab
3. Click on the 'Environment Variables' button
4. Look into the 'System Variables' pane
5. Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)
6. Double click on the Path entry
7. Enter your PHP directory at the end, including ';' before (e.g. ;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12)
8. Press OK
9. Restrart Wamp